# IMAP attachment retrieving command

Tags: imap

I am working on a mail client using IMAP and I am looking for the command for receiving the attachments of a message.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All message info is retrieved using the [`FETCH` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).  You have two options on how to use it, however.

First, you can retrieve the entire email message, verbatim.  In that case, you're going to need to include a MIME parser in your client to figure out the structure of the message.  (Each platform has at least one or two popular MIME parsers; since you haven't told us what you're coding in, I can't recommend one for you.)  Once you get the message structure from your MIME parser, you'll need some client logic to determine which parts are attachments.  It's worth looking at [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) to get you started.  In general, parts with a `Content-Disposition` starting with "`attachment`" are going to be attachments, but all mail client authors go through a phase of trial and error getting it right.  In order to download the entire email message, you'd issue the IMAP command

```
$ UID FETCH <uid> BODY.PEEK[]
```

Second, you can have the IMAP server parse the message structure for you by issuing a `FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE` (note: no square brackets).  You'll have to parse the returned BODYSTRUCTURE data yourself; the IMAP RFC [explains the format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.4.2) and gives a few examples.

```
# message, no attachments:
("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "ISO-8859-1" "FORMAT" "flowed") NIL NIL "7BIT" 1469 50 NIL NIL NIL NIL)

# message, one attachment
(("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "US-ASCII") NIL NIL "QUOTED-PRINTABLE" 56 1 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("AUDIO" "X-WAV" ("NAME" "voicemail.wav") NIL NIL "BASE64" 152364 NIL ("attachment" ("FILENAME" "voicemail.wav")) NIL NIL) "MIXED" ("BOUNDARY" "----_=_NextPart_001_01C4ACB3.5AA7B8E2") NIL NIL NIL)
```

Once you've determined which parts you're interested in, you can issue a `FETCH` for the displayable message body.  Your client can then just list the message attachments (parsed out of the `BODY` response) and can then go back and `FETCH` them if the user clicks on them.  So the IMAP commands you'd be issuing would be along the lines of:

```
$ UID FETCH <uid> (BODY ENVELOPE)   # get structure and header info
$ UID FETCH <uid> (BODY[1])         # retrieving displayable body
$ UID FETCH <uid> (BODY[2])         # retrieving attachment on demand
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the [IMAP v4 FETCH command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

Comment: ok, but things is that I am once all mail has been downloaded then after what ever email is I am selecting, this mail I want to download attachment. now once my mail has been downloaded and then I am try to download attachment; it will say the $ OK UID FETCH completed so what can I do.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Context.IO's files resource to quickly and easily fetch attachments.

http://context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/files#get